# Magento 2 - Backend (admin) login not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, backend

I try to login to the backend. I entere the correct credentials, but the form just reloads and nothing happens.

I deleted all cookies, but it makes no difference.

UPDATE: I tried it again. I entered incorrect credentials on purpose and then after it I entered the correct ones, and now it works. Strange bug...

Comment: is it giving an error of "Invalid Form Key, Please Refresh the Page" ??

Comment: No, nothing at all.

Comment: you have to try to add admin user create using command?

Comment: I think the problem is to redirect http to https(https to http), You should check config url admin page

Comment: @pankajparmar, I already have admin user...